# Moving Site Collection to different server

Tags: migration, site-collection

I have a site collection that is located on our project server that needs to be incorporated to our main SharePoint Enterprise server. As a little more background, the project server was setup first to give a small group access to SharePoint features it needed. Later on, SharePoint was setup company-wide by a contractor who had no knowledge of the original instance.

It is currently for example at http://projectserver.com/Engineering/Maintenance

We need it moved to http://companydomain/Engineering/Maintenace

The backup and restore tools only seem to move top-level domains as does the stsadm tool. What is my best option to do this?

Comment: You're trying to move the ProjectServer site collection or change the domain? AFAIK, you can't use STSADM to backup/restore PWA site collections because of the GUIDs PWA references in the database.

Comment: I am trying to move just the engineering site collection. It is not the root one. and move it to a similar spot on our enterprise sharepoint application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running 2010, simply do a export of the site collection and then import into the correct web application.

1. http://YOURCENTRALADMINURL/backups.aspx
2. Click Perform a site collection backup

After backup complete,

1. http://YOURCENTRALADMINURL/backups.aspx
2. Restore from a backup

Comment: The backup attempts made through here fail immediately (0 - 1 seconds in to the backup).

Comment: Hi there. The backup job will tell you why it fails. Otherwise, please try and do a backup using Powershell: a. Backup-SPSite -Identity http://SitecollectionURL -Path "\\UNCPATH\Backupsetname.bak" -force and then restore with this command : Restore-SPSite -Identity http://RestoreURL -Path "\\Backuplocation\backupname.bak" -force